# Creating a Console Application for Dynamics CRM 4.0

Tags: console-application, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-4

I'm pretty new to Dynamics CRM.

On the 2011 release, I followed the walkthrough on building a Console application that works with CRM, and developed some applications based on that walkthrough as the base;
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695803.aspx

Now I have to make one of those applications work on CRM 4.0, and I've not been able to find a walkthrough on how to create a console application for CRM 4.0. What dll's to import for a console applications, which steps to follow, I've failed after searching for last few hours. I'll be in your debt if someone can turn me into the right direction; a link to a walkthrough or tutorial would make my day.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect to the Crm 4 web services using either the WSDLs or SDK proxy classes. [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee704593.aspx) provides a pretty good overview of the options. Link to [Crm 4 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38).

To interact with the Crm data you will mainly be using the `CrmService`, all the web services available are described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb928392.aspx).

To create a web service reference check out [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb887784.aspx). And then a small snippet showing instantiation and use the CrmService can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc151016.aspx).

I think that should be enough to get you going, more code samples can found on the MSDN.